# How do one use `offsetof` to access a field in a standard conforming way?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, offsetof

Let's suppose I have a struct and extract the offset to a member:

```
struct A {
    int x;
};

size_t xoff = offsetof(A, x);
```

how can I, given a pointer to `struct A` extract the member in a standard conforming way? Assuming of course that we have a correct `struct A*` and a correct offset. One attempt would be to do something like:

```
int getint(struct A* base, size_t off) {
    return *(int*)((char*)base + off); 
}
```

Which probably will work, but note for example that pointer arithmetics only seem to be defined in the standard if the pointers are pointers of the same array (or one past the end), this need not be the case. So technically that construct would seem to rely on undefined behaviour.

Another approach would be

```
int getint(struct A* base, size_t off) {
    return *(int*)((uintptr_t)base + off);
}
```

which also probably would work, but note that `intptr_t` is not required to exist and as far as I know arithmetics on `intptr_t` doesn't need to yield the correct result (for example I recall some CPU has the capability to handle non-byte aligned addresses which would suggest that `intptr_t` increases in steps of 8 for each `char` in an array).

It looks like there's something forgotten in the standard (or something I've missed).

Comment: I'm pretty sure aliasing to `char*` and pointers that point into the same object (not necessarily array) are both valid. Waiting for an authoritative answer though.

Comment: `(char *)base` can be used to move around anywhere within `base` (and one past the end). Any object behaves like an array of size 1.

Comment: `return *(int*)((char*)base + off);` can readily fail as `int` access may be unaligned.  E.g. `int` access can cause bus fault on odd address.  OTOH OP did say "Assuming ... we have a correct struct A* and a correct offset"

Comment: Best to _access_ a field with with that field's type or `unsigned char` (No traps, no padding).

Comment: It is not clear is why does not code use `A->x` to access the field.  What do you what to do that `A->x` does not provide?  If all code has is `A` and the offset to field `x`, lack of the field type/size prevents accessing in a conforming manner.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **7.19  Common definitions `<stddef.h>`**, paragraph 3, `offsetof()` is defined as:

> The macros are
>
> ```
> NULL
> ```
>
> which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant; and
>
> ```
> offsetof(*type*, *member-designator*)
> ```
>
> which  expands  to  an  integer  constant  expression  that  has  type
>   `size_t`,  the *value* of which is the offset in bytes, to the
>   structure member (designated by *member-designator*), from the
>   beginning of its structure (designated by *type*).

So, `offsetoff()` returns an offset in *bytes*.

And **6.2.6.1 General**, paragraph 4 states:

> Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type
>   consist of
>   *n* × **CHAR_BIT** bits, where *n* is the size of an object of that type, in bytes.

Since **CHAR_BIT** is defined as the number of bits in a `char`, a `char` is one *byte*.

So, this is correct, per the standard:

```
int getint(struct A* base, size_t off) {
    return *(int*)((char*)base + off); 
}
```

That converts `base` to a `char *` and adds `off` bytes to the address.  If `off` is the result of `offsetof(A, x);`, the resulting address is the address of `x` within the `structure A` that `base` points to.

Your second example:

```
int getint(struct A* base, size_t off) {
    return *(int*)((intptr_t)base + off);
}
```

is dependent upon the result of the addition of the signed `intptr_t` value with the unsigned `size_t` value being unsigned.

Comment: The cited parts are quite irrelevant. The relevant parts of the standard would be the ones in 6.5 concerning pointer aliasing, or perhaps the parts regarding pointer arithmetic.  I don't see how the second example would fail. `intptr_t` is an unsigned integer type, not a pointer type. It does not do any pointer arithmetic so your assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: @Lundin - Yes, you're right.  For some reason, I read `intptr_t` as `int *`.  Revising the answer now, but first I need to think about what happens if `intptr_t` is signed.

Comment: Agree with @Lundin except `intptr_t` is a signed integer type vs. `uintptr_t`

Comment: @chux - Yes, it's signed.  But I'm trying to remember what happens when adding a signed and unsigned int.  The OP's code may be valid.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Adding signed type to equal rank unsigned type --> unsigned type.

Comment: @chux  Yes.  I've spent most of my programming life trying to avoid relying on such conversion rules, so I don't know them offhand.

Comment: @Lundin Also, I don't know why you think the sections I quoted are irrelevant.  They support the OP's method of using a `char *` and offset from `offsetof()` to find the address of a structure's field.  There may very well be *other* sections that also support the OPs method.

Comment: The OP seems to know how offsetof works. Main concerns here is if you can do pointer arithmetic on a struct and pointer conversions. And regarding implicit conversion rules: they are there whether you like them or not. Not knowing about them might cause you to write code that relies upon them, by accident.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the standard (6.5.6) only allows pointer arithmetic for arrays, is that structs may have padding bytes to sate alignment requirements. So doing pointer arithmetic inside a struct is indeed formally undefined behavior.

In practice, it will work as long as you know what you are doing. `base + off` cannot fail, because we know that there is valid data there and it is not misaligned, given that it is accessed properly.

Therefore `(intptr_t)base + off` is indeed much better code, as there is no longer any pointer arithmetic, but just plain integer arithmetic. Because `intptr_t` is an integer, it is not a pointer.

As pointed out in a comment, this type is not guaranteed to exist, it is optional as per 7.20.1.4/1. I suppose for maximum portability, you could switch to other types that *are* guaranteed to exist, such as `intmax_t` or `ptrdiff_t`. It is however arguable if a C99/C11 compiler without support for `intptr_t` is at all useful.

(There is a small type issue here, namely that `intptr_t` is a signed type, and not necessarily compatible with `size_t`. You might get implicit type promotion issues. It is safer to use `uintptr_t` if possible.)

The next question then is if `*(int*)((intptr_t)base + off)` is well-defined behavior. The part of the standard regarding pointer conversions (6.3.2.3) says that:

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>   undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any
>   integer type.

For this specific case, we *know* that we have a correctly aligned `int` there, so it is fine.

(I don't believe that any pointer aliasing concerns apply either. At least compiling with `gcc -O3 -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=2` doesn't break the code.)

Comment: "Because intptr_t is an integer, ... is guaranteed to exist ... compiler (C99/C11)" --> "`intptr_t` ... `uintptr_t` These types are _optional_." §7.20.1.4 1

Comment: @chux Ah, I learnt something new then! :) Will edit the answer, thanks.